# Make Vim only do a soft word-wrap, not hard word-wrap

Tags: vim, macvim

I've been using Vim for a week now. And I've noticed something.

I have textwidth unset, and I have wrap set. Now, my question is. Currently whenever I line longer than 120 characters (window width), it takes the last character, and just like that, wraps it. So if it's in the middle of a word it looks like this:

```
This is a very long sen|
tence, this looks very |
strange, don't you thin|
k?                     |
```

BTW, the `|` represents the text limit, very short in this case, to prove my point. So that says what my problem is, I would like a simply solution to this, as long as I don't lose any screen real estate.

Of course, the ideal solution would output the following, without modifying the text, only the output, the text remains in one line, but it appears to be spread over several:

```
This is a very long    |
sentence, this looks   |
very strange, don't you|
think?                 |
```

Thanks for any help you can provide. :)

Extra info:

- OS: Mac OSX Mountain Lion
- Using MacVim

I've tried the following:

```
set textwidth=120

set wrap
set linebreak

set fo=1
```

Comment: Some of the answers to http://stackoverflow.com/q/467739/684934 look promising.  (None are accepted, though.)

Comment: @bdares Thanks, I didn't see that one. Still, it doesn't solve my problem, none of the options.

Answer (score 24, accepted):

```
set linebreak
```

is enough. It doesn't work when `list` is on, though.

Comment: It is on. I do use `list`. :/

Comment: Well it's either one or the other. Sorry.

Comment: Is there no way around this? Maybe with a custom function that replaces this functionality?

Comment: No way that I know of: it's a low level feature. Typically the kind of thing you write a patch for.

Comment: I see, thanks for your answers. It's just that when I write text I like it without new lines. (Especially since I change it all the time). Nevertheless, thanks. :)

Comment: Has this changed? In my .vimrc I have both "set list" and "set lbr" and both are working.  Vim 8.0 on Arch Linux.

Comment: A lot of things can change in five years.

Comment: I think this has changed a little bit, now we can use list and linebreak at the same time. See the vim wiki link in the next answer for more details.

Answer (score 0):

My solution to this problem was [this Vim wiki](http://vim.wikia.com/wiki/Word_wrap_without_line_breaks) page.
Thanks to @romainl for convincing me to not use `list`.